# Problema en combobox dependiente en tabla pintada con while

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

Buenas tardes tengo un incomveniente estoy llenando una tabla en php con un while y  a la tabla le estoy inyectando combobox dependientes para luego poder almacenarlos de nuevo en la base de datos el ciclo en mostrar los campos de la base de datos y volverlos a guardar pero tengo un inconveniente al momento de seleccionar el padre se cambian todos los combos hijos de todas las celdas

Este es mi codigo

```
<?php 

$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prueba');


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabla dinamica</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/select2/css/select2.css">

    <script src="librerias/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/select2/js/select2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <br>

    <table border="1" >
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>PLACA</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>N° OT</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>CLIENTE</small></th> 
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>CENTRO DE COSTO</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>ASESOR</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>MODELO</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>COLOR</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>MOTIVO DE INGRESO</small></th> 
        <th ><small>ESTADO DE FASE</small></th>
        <th ><small>RESPONSABLE DE FASE </small></th>                    
        <th><small>TECNICO</small></th>
        <th><small>PROXIMA REVISION</small></th>
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>FECHA DE ENTRADA</small></th> 
        <th ><small>DIAS EN TALLER</small></th>                                    
        <th><small>NOTA TORRE</small></th> 
        <th class="bg-danger"><small>MONTO</small></th>
        <th><small>NOTA</small></th>
        <th><small>CARRO LISTO</small></th>

        <?php 



        $sql="SELECT id,placa,n_ot,cliente,c_costo,asesor,modelo,color,m_ing,f_ini_taller 
        from torre ";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


            ?>  
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $mostrar['placa'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['n_ot'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['cliente'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['c_costo'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['asesor'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['modelo'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['color'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['m_ing'] ?></td>




                <!--fase-->
                <td  ><select id="fase'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="fase">

                </select></td>
                <!-- RESPONSABLE D FACE-->
                <td  ><select name="r_fase" class="r_fase" >

                </select></td>


                <!-- TECNICOS-->
                <td><select name="tecnicos" class="tecnicos" >

                </select></td>

                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['f_ini_taller'] ?></td>
                <td>  





                </td>
                <?php           
            }
            ?>



        </tr>



    </table>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

  // Lista de fase
  $.post( 'fase.php' ).done( function(respuesta  )
  {

    $( '.fase' ).html(respuesta );
  });

  // lista de r_fase
  $('.fase').change(function()
  {

    var la_fase = $(this).val();


    // Lista de r_fase

    $.post( 'r_fase.php', { fase: la_fase} ).done( function( respuesta  )
    {

     // for ($i = $idtorre ;$i>4;$i++) {


        $( '.r_fase' ).html( respuesta);

     });
});

  // Lista de r_fase
  $( 'r_fase' ).change( function()
  {
    var fac = $(this).children('option:selected').html();
    alert( 'EL RESPONSABLE DE ESTA FACE ES :' + fac );
  });


})


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   // Lista de Continentes
   $.post( 'tecnicos.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
   {
    $( '.tecnicos' ).html( respuesta );
   });



</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Olvidaste decirnos cuál es el problema, el mensaje de error, en qué parte del código ... ¿?

Comment: No entiendo nada. Por favor explícate mejor y evita poner todo en mayúscula, es desagradable. Gracias.

Comment: tengo un tabla que dibujo o relleno con un while verdad pero a una fila le coloco un select padre y a otra un select hijo el cual relleno de base de datos con jquery lo q no logro es q me fije la fila el cual va a cambiar el select hijo xq me el padre me cambia todos